# What will be the cube root of the number obtained from the given information?

Tags: sums-of-squares

$6bcde$ is a five-digit number. If $6-d=x, c=y$ and $xy$ is a two digit square number in which each digit is a square number. If $b = p$, $e = q$ and $pq$ is a two-digit perfect square number in which each digit cube, the cube root of $6bcde$ is?

This question was on an exam I had taken about a month ago. Even now, I can't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $xy$ is a two-digit square number in which each number is a square, then $xy = 49$;  this is the only such number.  So $x = 4$ and $y = 9$.  Similarly, the only two-digit square number in which each digit is a cube is 81, so $p = 8$ and $q = 1$.  All together, then, the number $6bcde$ is 68921, and $\sqrt[3]{68921} = 41.$

Comment: I thought $xy$ to be $x*y$. Don't you think information regarding this should have been given in the paper?

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya:  I thought that too, at first.  But if $x*y = 49$, then you must have $x = y = 7$.  This means that $d = -1$, which is impossible.  So I looked for another interpretation, and it worked.